# Call Arguments? and Explicit call?

Tags: calldata

I am trying to understand the arguments of the built-in Solidity's (or EVM's: I am not sure) call function. I know it has 4 arguments. I am trying to understand the call function at:
[Syntax Error in Program](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71895/parsererror-expected-identifier-but-got-address/71902)

The implicit call method in the above link is:

```
 a.blah.value(ValueToSend)(2, 3);
```

I am telling the 4 argumens, kindly let me correct if I am wrong:

1. Amount of gas: calculated by the EVM system using some formula?
2. Destination address: a.blah
3. Ether= Value to send
4. input/output: input = 2 & 3: output=?

Is the following the explicit version of above call but it would invoke the fallback function instead of blah(...), is this correct?:

```
a.call.value(ValueToSend)(2,3)?
```

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Solidity's "call" function mean?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8270/what-does-soliditys-call-function-mean)

Comment: The sentence `a.blah.value(ValueToSend)(2, 3)` is interpreted as _call function `blah` from contract `a` with parameters 2, 3 and send `ValueToSend` wei_. On the other hand `a.call.value(ValueToSend)(2,3)` is a syntax error on solidity 0.5 because it only accepts bytes as parameter to call.

Comment: And the output of call would be true/false along with some argument?