# Error with this.balance

Tags: addresses, calldata, callcode

```
pragma solidity 0.5.9;
contract Testing{

function participate()public  payable{ 
        uint winner = 9;
        require(msg.value == 0.1 ether);



        if ( winner==9)
        {

           require(msg.sender.call.value(this.balance)());

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

> > solc testing8_2.sol testing8_2.sol:13:42: Error: Member "balance" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract
> >     Testing. Use "address(this).balance" to access this address member.
> >                require(msg.sender.call.value(this.balance)());

But if I try:

```
if ( winner==9)
        {

           require(msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)());

        }
```

I get the following error message:

> > solc testing8_2.sol testing8_2.sol:13:20: Error: Wrong argument count for function call: 0 arguments given but expected 1. This function
> >     requires a single bytes argument. Use "" as argument to provide empty
> >     calldata.
> >                require(msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)());
> >                        ^--------------------------------------------^ testing8_2.sol:13:12: Error: No matching declaration found after
> >     argument-dependent lookup.
> >                require(msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)());
> >                ^-----^

Somebody please guide me how to solve this problem:

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing the bytes parameter for `call`:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.9;

contract Testing {

    function participate() public payable{ 
        uint winner = 9;
        require(msg.value == 0.1 ether);

        if (winner == 9)
        {
           (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)("");
            require(success, "Transfer failed.");

        }
    }
}
```

**What is the purpose of the bytes argument?**

Since you only want to send ether to the address, but not call a function at that address, the bytes argument is just an empty `""`. Let's assume you would want to instead call a `deposit()` function at the `msg.sender` address. You would then write:

```
function makeDeposit(address bankAddress) public payable {
        bytes32 functionHash = keccak256("deposit()");      
        bytes4 function4bytes = bytes4(functionHash);
        bytes payload = abi.encode(function4bytes);

        if (msg.value > 0) {
            (bool success,) = bankAddress.call.value(msg.value)(payload);
            require(success, "Ether transfer failed.");
        }      
}
```

Example taken from this great tutorial on [how to use call.value](https://medium.com/@luizhamilton29/how-to-use-call-value-7b275ec7f568).

Comment: And of course, since this specific function doesn't take any input arguments, you could simply save that payload as a constant in the contract, in order to avoid calculating it every time the function is called: `bytes private constant payload = abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("deposit()")));`.

Comment: You mean we can do the samething as:
bankAddres.deposit.value(msg.value)();
The reason for converting the name into an id and then converting the id into bytes is that call only accepts bytes as @soliditydeveloper.com mentioned. Is using the name deposit not better for readability instead of assigning an id to the name?

Comment: @zak100 I don't think `bankAddress.deposit.value` is a supported way of writing it. The comment from @goodvibration simply states the correct fact you could save some gas by doing the computation outside the function as a one-time constant variable. That is because it never changes, actually even if `deposit` would have input arguments, you could still do it outside. If would then simply be `keccak256("deposit(address,uint256)")`.

It would be nice to have Solidity features on top to make this more readable.

Comment: It seems there is a minor short-cut like `abi.encodeWithSelector(this.deposit.selector)`, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @soliditydeveloper.com, I think use of deposit as function name is correct, please see the link: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72072/call-arguments-and-explicit-call?noredirect=1#comment87606_72072.